# Fastest method to compare two arrays for find equal value on Google app script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have two `arrays` as below.

```
bulkSheet[] - Original array
resultsArray[] -  Checking array
```

I am comparing first element of '`bulkSheet`' array with '`resultArray`'. Below code is what I have done so far. It executes fine but take long time and gives `Exceeded maximum execution time` error.

```
for(var line in bulkSheet) {
  for (var line2 in resultsArray)
  {
    if(bulkSheet[line][0] == resultsArray[line2][0])
    {
      // matched items
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any fastest way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Don't use an inner loop.  Instead use the `indexOf(value)` method.  If the return value from `indexOf()` is -1, then there is no match.  If there is a match, it will return the index placement of the match in the array being tested.  From the index number you can return that value, or overwrite it if you wish.  So, `var isMatched = secondArray.indexOf(value from loop of first array);  if (isMatched !== -1) {var matchedValFromArray2 = arrayTwo[isMatched]};`

Comment: Thank you @sandy-good, you saved my day !

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  The question that people referenced as possibly already having the answer, does not show the method I explained.  Do you really need to test that both arrays are identical, or do you need to have the code do something if there isn't a match for a particular value?  There may be some misunderstanding about the specifics of what you need.  Personally, I don't see this question as a duplicate, and voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the vote to reopen. I wanted to identify if there isn't a match for a particular value. your method made it faster. I didn't aware about indexOf() method. Thanks again,cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @sandy-good !,
If it is an 1D array we can use indexOf() method.

```
for(var line in firstArray) 
{
 var isMatched = secondArray.indexOf(firstArray[line]); 
 if (isMatched !== -1) 
 {
   var matchedValFromArray2 = secondArray[isMatched]
 };
}
```

If you want to compare 2D array (or two rows of a spreadsheet), you can use `.join()` method.

```
for(var i in firstArray)
{
  var duplicate = false;
  for(var j in secondArray)
  {
    if(firstArray[i].join() == secondArray[j].join())
    {
      var matchedValFromArray2 = firstArray[i];
      break;
    }
   }
 }
```